# AngularJs- how to combine two $scope properties in the view and order by timestamp?

Tags: angularjs

Say I have `$scope.someItems` which looks like `{key1a: {val:'someval', time:timestamp}, key2a: {val:'someval', time:timestamp}, key3a: {val:'someval', time:timestamp} }}`

I also have a second object `$scope.moreItems` which looks like `{key1b: {val:'someval', time:timestamp}, key2b: {val:'someval', time:timestamp}, key3b: {val:'someval', time:timestamp} }}`

In the view, I want to display the all the item val's in `$scope.someItems` and `$scope.moreItems` in a list ordered by timestamp (time property).

How would you accomplish this, only through the view code, assuming you have no access to modify the controller (so one cannot combine objects in the controller etc.).

Comment: Without modifying the controller? Chances are slim to none. To reap the benefits of `orderBy` and `filter` from the repeater functions you need to have an array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

As @tymeJV comment states this should be done in the controller (remember angular.js controllers are actually the viewModel layer since angular isn't an mvc but an mvvm - So It's perfectly correct to handle this data **view** manipulation there, without changing the data source, stored in a controller). But if you feel you must do it view code then you can Use a Directive!

just pass the directive both arrays as attrs. in the directive combine the lists and take care of ordering, filtering etc. then you can just use the Directive in the view template! very angularish solution (For a problem you probably invented)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible only with view code. 
I would use some library like lodash or underscore and do it in the controller:

http://jsfiddle.net/WRtqV/304/

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in allItems">{{key}}: {{value | json}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>


function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.someItems = {key1a: {val:'someval', time:1234}, key2a: {val:'someval', time:324234}, key3a: {val:'someval', time:54234} };

    $scope.moreItems = {key1b: {val:'someval', time:2423423}, key2b: {val:'someval', time:234234}, key3b: {val:'someval', time:54353453} }

    $scope.allItems = _.extend($scope.someItems, $scope.moreItems);
}
```